# Carbon Brush Specific Resistivity and Wear

Tags: dc-motor

Kindly ask for knowledge share and support about Dc motor commutation principal.

I have a brush wear issue on a DC motor with brushes which I try to understand the reason. As I read in the literature, I see that sparking is an issue and could be solved by using higher brush material resistance, I did like this and used some increased specific resistivity having brushes, but I have lost some RPM at the same voltage in comparison to low resistive brushes.

Could you please explain me what is the physic behind that , why the RPM reduces if I use high resistive brushes ?

And generally why higher resistive brushes being exposed to lower sparking during commutation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Higher voltage drop across the brush. Easy to crosscheck by predicting RPM loss from motor current, brush resistance and Kv. Possibly also higher friction.

Comment: Hello Together,

Thanks for your help. Just one question, I observe that the wear amount is also proportional to the winding amount in armature slots, I have tested armatures with 1x42 and 1x58 windings for brush wear amount and seen that when the winding numbers are increased, wear on brushes increase too. Is that related to the armature resistance and inductivity of armatures ? How could this behavior be electrically explained , I use Same brush holder same springs same brushes namely same configuration only winding turns of armature was different.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the motor to be doing anything useful, there's current passing through the windings on the armature, and the windings are arranged in the slots, and in their connections to the commutator such that the current in (most of) the windings is producing positive torque. As the armature rotates, coils that are leaving the field under one pole and entering the field of the next one need to reverse current to maintain that direction of torque.

The windings each have some inductance, so some effort is needed to cause that current to collapse and then build in the opposite direction. Most of that is done with shaping the field, by shaping the tips of the pole pieces, rotating the brush gear some degrees, or on larger machines using additional poles in the field assembly.

None of that is sufficient under all conditions, and there's always some energy left in the field around the winding in the slot, so as the commutator bar comes into contact with the brush, there's a potential there relative to the next bar that has the other end of the winding already under a brush (may be the same one, or a different brush of the same polarity depending on the winding pattern). The resistance of the brush acts as a sink for the energy so that the current can decay, so a larger resistivity allows the decay to be quicker, such that the current has decayed and reversed by the time the bar leaves the other side of the brush.

As you've found, the resistivity of the brush causes a voltage drop in the armature circuit, so the voltage at the brush face is lower, reducing speed and efficiency. There are brush materials that have anisotropic resistivity, produced by the pressing process, so that the resistance along the brush from the shunt at the back is low, but the resistance across the face is higher. Other brushes can have different materials sandwiched together to put the high resistivity material only at the edges. Very large machines may have multiple brushes slightly staggered around the commutator to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Hello Together,

Thanks for your help. Just one question, I observe that the wear amount is also proportional to the winding amount in armature slots, I have tested armatures with 1x42 and 1x58 windings for brush wear amount and seen that if the winding numbers are increased, wear on brushes increase too. Is that related to the armature resistance and inductivity of armatures ? How could this behavior be electrically explained , I use Same brush holder same springs same brushes namely same configuration only winding turns of armature was different.
Thanks.

Comment: A higher turn count will increase the inductance, and also increases the EMF generated at a particular speed, so the voltage at the brush face will be higher, so a higher resistivity material would be more optimal. Typically a higher turn count armature will have a lower operating current at the same load torque, so resistive losses in the brush will be lower, making a higher resistivity material tolerable.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please explain me what is the physic behind that , why the RPM reduces if I use high resistive brushes ?
>
> And generally why higher resistive brushes being exposed to lower sparking during commutation

The change in RPM is due to the field voltage of the armature being lowered by the resistive brushes in series. Lower currents would be observed too which would effect the spark potential at commutation.